# Creating and deploying a visual webpart using VS 2012

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to sharepoint. I managed to create a visual web part in VS 2012. But I don't know how to deploy it properly.

I only added a button control to the webpart page. After that I used F5 to deploy it. I selected "Deploy as farm solution" option while creating the project.

How can I view the output of my project in SharePoint 2013? How can I debug it? Is there any configurations to be made for deploying?

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy and see your webpart in the sharepoint site, pls follow the instruction given in the following link.

http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/visual-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Here is the steps to debug a web part in SharePoint :

Step 1: open the project and set the appropriate breakpoints.

Step 2: Create a Web Part Page on the default SharePoint site.

Step 3: Add the Web Part to the page.

Step 4:

• Attach the debugger to the W3wp process.

• On the Debug menu in Visual Studio .NET,click Processes.

• Verify that the Show system processes check box is selected.

• Verify that the Show processes in all sessions check box is selected.

• Under Available Processes, click W3wp.exe in the Process list, and then click Attach.

• Under Choose the program types that you want to debug, select Common Language Runtime, and then click OK, Then Close

Hope this helps you,

Reference,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583148(office.11).aspx

If you feel my above answer is correct, please mark it as answer, so that it would help others too.

Comment: Step 4: Press F5 in visual studio. This will open the sharepoint site to which solution is being deployed to.

Comment: Step 5 : Browse the URL to which the webpart is added. Control will go to Visual Studio debugger automatically.